# Commerce orders - header

Tags: commerce, search

On the orders admin page you have options to change fields in your table and sort fields, ect. In the headers option I have 'global: view order form' selected, and above the table there is a box where you can search for order numbers. I want to be able to not only search for order numbers, but also search for customer names, dates, money amounts, ect. Can you add in search criteria to that header?

Answer (score 0):

Did yout try simply add new filters? [image: filters]

For example, user:

- Add Filter Criteria
- Chose Filter - User
- Search for "name" field
- Select "User: Name"
- Check "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change"
- Click "Apply"

That's all you need to do. I should notice that for amount and date you can expose operator for your own needs.

[image: view's filters]

In the same way you can add SORT CRITERIAS

Comment: Thank you so much - I tried using filter criteria but was selecting one wrong category. It works! Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help!